# How to change day timestamp to month timestamp in Glue and sagemaker?

Tags: python, pyspark, time, prediction, target

i have timestamp data and this is daily timestamp like below.

```
   date      sku   unitprice    trand_item    target
2018-01-01    A      10            Black        3
2018-01-02    A      10            Black        7
2018-01-03    A      10            Black        0
2018-01-04    A      10            Black        13
.
.
.
2017-08-01    B      20            White        4
2017-08-02    B      20            White        0
2017-08-03    B      20            White        17
2017-08-04    B      20            White        9
.
.
.
```

It has 25 sku. So, it has 25 different timestamps in one data frame. (A, B, C....)

I want to make this monthly data like below.

```
   date      sku   unitprice    trand_item    target
2018-01-01    A      10            Black        30
2018-02-01    A      10            Black        70
2018-03-01    A      10            Black        40
2018-04-01    A      10            Black        130
.
.
.
2017-08-01    B      20            White        40
2017-09-01    B      20            White        40
2017-10-01    B      20            White        170
2017-11-01    B      20            White        90
.
.
.
```

How can i do this using 'Spark code' and 'Python code' for each 'SKU'?

Comment: That link is Grouping date by month. Yes it is fit to my question but i need group date by month for 'each SKU'.

Also, i have categorical columns in my dataframe...

Could you give a solution or example of code? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: You should be able to adapt that answer to your needs. I would group by SKU first then within each SKU, group by month.